# Scraping algorithm for open graph in nodejs

Tags: algorithm, node.js, logic, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to get open graph metadata from an URL using nodejs (with cheerio),
using the code bellow.

I have this thing to fill:    `var result={};`

```
  for (var ogCounter = 0; ogCounter < metalist.length; ogCounter++) {
    if (!utils.isEmpty(metalist[ogCounter].attribs.property) && !utils.isEmpty(metalist[ogCounter].attribs.content)) {
        if (metalist[ogCounter].attribs.property.indexOf('og') == 0) {
            var ogname = metalist[ogCounter].attribs.property.split(':');
            var property = ogname[1];
            var content = metalist[ogCounter].attribs.content;

            if (utils.isEmpty(result[property])) {
                result[property] = content;
            } else {
                if (result[property].push) {
                    result[property].push(content);
                } else {
                   result[property] = [result[property], content];
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

After I populate the result I converted in a JSon and with this code I get something like:

```
type: "video",
image: "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/fWNaR-rxAic/mqdefault.jpg",
video: [
"http://www.youtube.com/v/fWNaR-rxAic?version=3&amp;autohide=1",
"application/x-shockwave-flash",
"1920",
"1080"
]
```

But the thing I want is something like:

```
type: "video",
image: "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/fWNaR-rxAic/mqdefault.jpg",
video: {
"http://www.youtube.com/v/fWNaR-rxAic?version=3&amp;autohide=1",
{ 
type:"application/x-shockwave-flash",
width:"1920",
height:"1080"
}
}
```

I'm trying this "if" but it doesn't work:

```
 if (utils.isEmpty(result[property])) {
                    result[property] = content;
                } else {
                    if (result[property].push) {
                        result[property].push(content);
                    } else {
                        var subresult={};
                        subresult[name[2]]=content;
                        subresult[property]=result[property] ;

                        result[property] = subresult;
                    }
                }
```

I don't want to cycle all the meta 2 times and I'm not good with javascript and nodejs function... Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Happy to help but you'll get quicker responses if you post code that can actually run. Right would anyone wanting to help would have to reconstruct the rest of your program.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky because of how you want to display `og:video`. I don't think you can do it that way. The easiest thing to do would be to assign it an identifier for example `name` and have it at the same level as `og:video:width`

Example result

```
{
  "type": "video.other",
  "url": "http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/video.html",
  "title": "Simple Plan",
  "video": {
    "name": "http://www.youtube.com/v/Y4MnpzG5Sqc?version=3&amp;autohide=1",
    "type": "application/x-shockwave-flash",
    "width": "398",
    "height": "224",
    "release_date": "2012-05-29T21:30"
  }
}
```

How it could be done,

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio')
var request = require('request')

var url = 'http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/video.html';
var result = {};

request(url, function(error, response, body) {
  var $ = cheerio.load(body);

  var meta = $('meta')
  var keys = Object.keys(meta)

  keys.forEach(function(key){
    if ( meta[key].attribs 
         && meta[key].attribs.property 
         && meta[key].attribs.property.indexOf('og') == 0
       ) 
    {
      var og = meta[key].attribs.property.split(':');

      if(og.length > 2) {
        if(result[og[1]]) {
          if (typeof result[og[1]] == 'string' 
             || result[og[1]] instanceof String
             ) 
          {
            var set = {};
            set['name'] = result[og[1]];
            set[og[2]] = meta[key].attribs.content;
            result[og[1]] = set;
          }
          else {
            ex_set = result[og[1]];
            ex_set[og[2]] = meta[key].attribs.content;
            result[og[1]] = ex_set;
          }
        }
        else {
          var set = {};
          set[og[2]] = meta[key].attribs.content;
          result[og[1]] = set;
        }
      }
      else {
        result[og[1]] = meta[key].attribs.content;
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2));

});
```

Comment: Correct, it is not possible to have the data structure as requested in JS, because in an _object_ every property needs to have a name. What would be possible, is to replace the outer square brackets with curly ones – thus creating video as an _array_ with two entries, the first one a string value containing the URL, and the second one an object with the “meta data”. But I don’t see any actual benefit to that – having to switch from accessing everything else in that data structure as object properties, and only at this point index-based would be rather confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer. @phwd totally answered the question, but I thought it'd be nice to make a more general solution that parsed all `meta` tags to `n` levels.

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
  request = require('request'),
  url = 'http://philippeharewood.com/facebook/video.html',
  result = {},
  attr = function( tag, prop ){ return tag.attribs && tag.attribs[prop] || ""; }

request( url, function( err, res, body ) {

  var metas = cheerio.load(body)('meta')
  var keys = Object.keys(metas)

  keys.forEach(function(i){
    var meta = metas[i],
      property = attr(meta,'property'),
      parts = property.split(":");

    if ( property ) {
      var og = property.split(':'),
        parent = result;

      for ( var j = 0; j < og.length; j++ ){
        var token = og[j],
          current = parent[token],
          name;

        if ( j+1 == og.length ) { // leaf node

          // expected leaf is already a branch so append a name attr
          if ( current instanceof Object ) name = token;
          // leaf should take the value given
          else parent[token] = attr(meta,'content');

        } else { // branch node

          // if no such branch exists, make one
          if ( !(current instanceof Object) ) {
            // if the branch is already a leaf, move value to name attr
            if ( typeof current == "string" ) name = current;
            current = {};
            parent[token] = current;  
          }
        }
        if ( name ) current["name"] = name;
        name = undefined
        parent = current;
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(JSON.stringify( result.og, undefined, 2));

});
```